# GUI Tool to configure SFTP in Mac OS X Server?

Tags: mac, mac-osx, file-sharing, sftp, osx-leopard

Is there a GUI tool out there to configure SFTP for Mac OS? I have SFTP running fine, but I have no idea if it's possible to restrict access to certain Shares etc. Server Admin just lets you configure options for FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFTP doesn't work with shares. It is part of the SSH server bundle, and allows access to whatever the user login in has access to, no more, no less. There is a GUI to enable SSH (Remote Login), the rest is editing configuration files, there is no GUI that I know of for this.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't anything that will give you a GUI utilizing the built in SSH setup in OS X, there are programs such as [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com/features.html) (shareware) or [MySecureShell](http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/) (OSS, but not exactly user friendly). With these programs you can set accounts and where they are restricted to.